# How to generate a Haddock inline code span that takes up a whole line

Tags: haskell, haddock

In Haddock, the "inline code"¹ markup, `@...@`, is the same as the "code block" markup,

```
@
...
@
```

How can I write a single-line Haddock comment that consists only of an *inline* code span, without it being misinterpreted as a block?  A comment like

```
-- |@/code/ span@
```

renders as the block

> ```
> code span
> ```

instead of the desired inline

> `code span`

The context, in case more examples help, is that I'm writing a data type that represents a BNF grammar, and so I have a number of types that look like the following:

```
-- |@/term/ ::=@
data Term = Var Name       -- ^@/name/@
          | Plus Term Term -- ^@/term/ + /term/@
          | Print Term     -- ^@print /term/@
```

This example corresponds to the grammar

```
term ::= name
      |  term + term
      |  print term
```

and so the grammar is embedded in the Haddock comments.  But since Haddock parses those `@...@` comments as blocks, the output is unnecessarily tall, and is inconsistent when some lines have extra comment text (e.g., `-- ^@double /term/@ – syntax sugar`).

---

¹ A.k.a. "monospaced" or "typewriter".

Comment: Are you sure you need this? Sounds like [you're using comments wrong](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/), after all a Haskell ADT definition _is_ already pretty much a grammar. This reminds me of [`i++; // Increment i by 1`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3/29181) style coding. — If you really need BNF, well, provide it as a single plaintext chunk, but not as Haddock inline comments.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The BNF [already exists](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual003.html), I'm just instantiating it in Haskell. The point of the comments is to line up the constructors, and perhaps more importantly the fields, with the productions/nonterminals in the BNF rules. E.g., in the production `Let Ident [Binder] (Maybe Term) Term Term`, which `Term` means what?  It helps to see that this production is `let /ident/ [/binders/] [: /term/] := /term/ in /term/`.  So the comments are half "why" and half "what does this mean?".

Comment: @leftaroundabout (And even if you aren't convinced by this use case, the "inline code/code block" ambiguity is something that I've encountered with Haddock before.)

Comment: Yeah, me too, Haddock code-snippet syntax is certainly a bit annoying. But IMO it just doesn't make sense to have “line-spanning inline code”. — I'm indeed not convinced with this use case: if you want _readability_ then improve your _code_, not your comments. Type operators / infix constructors / type synonyms can help here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I tried that at first – and I'm certainly not done iterating on the design of this AST – but with 5-argument type constructors, three of whose arguments are the same type, it gets tricky to do. Type synonyms aren't necessarily a bad choice (although the number needed becomes a bit of a pain), but I've decided that what's *more* important is at-a-glance correspondence with the BNF source, as this is part of a verification-related project where it's important to know that your model is of the right thing. (Although we're not verifying this code itself, I'm in that mindset.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggested dirty hack. Your problem is that your lines only have code, and not text, correct? Well, just add, after the code, a bit of meaningless text. You can use the `&#xH;` format to insert hexcodes of unicode characters, for example zero-width or nonbreaking spaces. I would imagine that this would let you convince haddock that you are in an inline rather than block context.